# Is it possible to export two jqxgrids at a time using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to export 2 jqxgrids at a time. i'm using this code to export single grid. i'm not able to get the solution to export 2 grids at a time.

Any help will be highly appreciated..:)`

```
      $("#btnExport").click(function() {
var sel = $("#combofiletype").jqxComboBox('getSelectedIndex');
if (sel == 0) {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'pdf', 'Filename', true, null, true);
} else if (sel == 1) {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', 'Filename', true, null, true);
} else if (sel == 2) {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', 'Filename', true, null, true);
} else if (sel == 3) {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'html', 'Filename', true, null, true);
} else if (sel == 4) {
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xml', 'Filename', true, null, true);
}
});
```

Comment: any error you have encountered?

Comment: Right now i'm exporting only one grid in the above code. I tried in different ways to export 2nd grid but not successful. i miserably want to export 2nd grid @CurseStacker

Comment: The question is quite strange taking the fact that jqxGrid does not have feature to export data to PDF :). It can export to xls, csv, tsv, json, html and xml, but PDF is not in the list of supported formats so I think that the answer of your question is No, because jqxGrid can't export to PDF at least in its newest 3.7.1 version.